# Show that a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Determine whether or not $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x+y<0\}$ is bounded.

Definition of boundedness is: a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is bounded if there exists $R>0$ such that $\Vert a\Vert<R$ for all $a\in A$.

Obviously, the set is not bounded by sketching the set in a coordinate system. I try to prove it by definition. If $x+y<0$, we get $(x+y)^2>0$, and so $x^2+y^2+2xy>0$, or, $\Vert (x,y)\Vert^2+2xy>0$. Since $-2xy>2y^2$ whenever $x+y<0$, we then get $\Vert (x,y)\Vert^2>2y^2$, and hence $\Vert (x,y)\Vert>\sqrt{2}\vert y\vert$. How do I conclude from here by definition?

If I use the definition, I think I should use the negation of it, i.e. a set $A$ *is not* bounded if for all $R>0$ there exists $(x,y)\in A$, depending on $R$, such that $\Vert (x,y)\Vert \geq R$. If I let $R>0$ be given, how exactly do I find a such $(x,y)$ that satisfies the inequality?

Comment: *If I let* $R>0$ *be given, how exactly do I find a such* $(x,y)$ *that satisfies the inequality?* --- I made a quick sketch, and every point on the negative $x$-axis is in the set, which is also easy to see algebraically since $x<0$ and $y=0$ implies $x+y<0.$ Now note that $(-R,0)$ is in the set $\ldots$

Comment: Just use that for any $R>0$ you have that the point $(x,-x-1)$ is always contained in your set and if $x=2R$ you get $||(x,-x-1)||>\sqrt{2}R>R.

Comment: @YgorArthur Why is $||(2R,-2R-1)||>\sqrt{2}R$? Is it because, putting $y=-2R-1$ in my post, you get $\sqrt{2}\vert y\vert =\sqrt{2}(2R+1) > \sqrt{2}R$?

Comment: Pick an $x$ and a $y$. Any ones you like. Add them. Is it negative? If now, can you fix that situation? When you can, then try picking $x$ and $y$ to be larger, but still have a negative sum. Can do you it? Now try to figure out how to pick $x$ and $y$ to be large and larger and larger, but still have a negative sum. If you can do that, you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your set, which I denote by $A$ is bounded. Then, find $R>0$ such that $A$ is contained in the ball $B(0,R)$. Now the point $(x,y)=(R+2,-R-3)$ is in $A$ but not in $B(0,R)$.

Comment: Why to choose a complicated point instead of $(-R-1,0)$?

Comment: @jjagmath I don't think it's complicated. $-R-3=-(R+3)$

Comment: To prove that $(x,y)\not\in B(0,R)$ you need to calculate  $\|(R+2,-R-3)\| = \sqrt{2R^2+10R+13}$ instead of $\|(-R-1, 0)\| = R+1$

Answer (score 0):

I think the most intuitive way of thinking of unboundedness is via sequences:

A set $X$ is unbounded if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ such that $||x_n|| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

In terms of your set:
For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ choose $(x_n, y_n) := (-n-1, 0)$,
then clearly $(x_n, y_n)$ is in your set and also $||(x_n, y_n)|| = |-n-1| \to \infty$, assuming euclidian norm. Thus the set is unbounded.